# видеоплеер GoogleDrive - PHP

Tags: php, html, iframe, видео, google-drive

Необходимо сделать веб плеер который бы играл видео с `Google Drive`. **НО! НЕ ДЕЛАЛ РЕДИРЕКТ** на страницу с просмотром, а играл в плеере на моем сайте. После долгого гугления удалось только воткнуть на сайт, превью видео которое не открывается на полный экран и в рамке видео (справа вверху) висит не убиваемая `pop-out` кнопка "*открыть это видео в новой вкладке*". Вот формат ссылки:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item my" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byc08IJpZRKpV3dwQkU3M2poYWM/preview"></iframe>
```

Второй вариант, это замена ссылки на такое:

```
<video src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3IHrR1L9f6JaUlfTzhJZE1uUHc&export=download"></video>
```

**НО** проблема в том, что если файл больше 80мб он не играет(связано с тем, что гугл не может его проверить его на вирусы). Эта опция не отключается в настройках или где-то еще, а перехват ссылки юзлесс потому что submit в ссылке каждый раз меняется.

Если кто сталкивался с гугл драйв АПИ подскажите что можно сделать?
возможно ли всё таки открыть видео на полный экран и убрать эту `pop-out` кнопку или есть третий вид ссылок без всех этих проблем?

Answer (score 0):

Кнопку убрать не знаю как. Возможно это и невозможно. А вот открыть видео на все экран можно, добавив параметр allowfullscreen="1". Например так:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item my" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byc08IJpZRKpV3dwQkU3M2poYWM/preview" width="416" height="312" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
```